# make image draggable and resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i would like to know how i can make my images draggable and resizable at the same time. i made the draggable part work but not resizable my code stops working when i put both of them together.

```js
 var modal = document.getElementById('boxes');
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("imgdisplay");
  $('#imgdisplay').draggable();
  $('#imgdisplay').resizable();
  function clickedPhoto(src) {
    modalImg.src = src;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

what i did was to create a div around my image id= fotos and imgdisplay is the id of my image thats all i did

```js
 var modal = document.getElementById('boxes');
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("imgdisplay");
 
  
  function clickedPhoto(src) {
    modalImg.src = src;   $('#imgdisplay').resizable();
$('#fotos').draggable();
    
  }
```